# CodeIgniter: parenthesis being replaced by character codes

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

While making an edit to a tag (as in a tag in WordPress, for example, and not a HTML tag) in an application I've written using CodeIgniter, the parenthesis in the tag name were swapped out for their character codes.

So instead of: "Sound Surveillance System (SOSUS)" I got: "`Sound Surveillance System &#40;SOSUS&#41;`".

I have added dozens of tags that contain pairs of parenthesis with no similar problems.

I have no code anywhere in the application that would instruct this change.

It happens even if I change the acronym within the parenthesis to anything.

I've written it again, just in case there were invisible characters to no avail.

It's happening in any browser I try.

So far, this weirdness is restricted to this tag. By that, I mean that if I take the exact wording and add it as another tag, it does the same thing.

I don't even know if this anything to do with CodeIgniter, given that it's associated with just this tag (that I am aware of).

Either I'm having a massive "D'oh!" moment, or this is something weird. Either way, some help would be excellent.

Comment: You mean you name your tag like <div name="Sound Surveillance System (SOSUS)"></div> ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I've just made an edit to clarify what type o tag.

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter. But I still didn't get your question clearly. Do you mean your input from view page is "Sound Surveillance System (SOSUS)" and what you receive on controller is "Sound Surveillance System &#40;SOSUS&#41;" ?

Comment: As I said, while making an edit to the tag within the application. When I save the tag, it's changed. I'm using the application, not building it. Although I'm in the code now, given this weird bug.